# Surface 3 stuck on boot screen mid Windows 10 Upgrade

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, microsoft-surface

Today I tried upgrading a Surface 3 to Windows 10 from Windows 8.1 using the windows upgrade app. After several hours it prompted to use an external drive (USB drive) to provide extra space for the upgrade. The upgrade proceeded to 25% and did a reboot, to where it had been stuck on the 'Surface' boot screen for several hours.

What is the solution to continue the upgrade?

Comment: Make more room on the primary storage device and try again or simply use an external flash drive instead of the upgrade tool.  Hope you realize that unless it was acvtivated before July 29 2016 Windows 10 won't activate now with your Windows 8 key

Comment: I have bought a valid Windows 10 key